# "Function eregi() is deprecated" tried preg_match - no bueno

Tags: php, eregi

I've read many threads here about this being deprecated and tried replacing it with preg_match but I don't know php enough to fix the rest of the line.

Been enjoying Fotoholder for years, I would switch to a newer similar single file gallery code but then I would lose all my descriptions in the gallery.

Please help resurrect Fotopholder! 
( https://github.com/offsky/Fotopholder )

Here are the 2 parts that have eregi:

```html
 
     if(substr($entry,0,1)!="." && !preg_match("#_cache#i",$entry) && is_dir($path."/".$entry)) {
```

and the 2nd eregi:

```html
      if(substr($entry,0,1)!="." && !eregi("_cache",$entry)) {
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Don't you just need to use the `preg_match` function like you did in the first block?

Comment: If you're new to PHP, just disable the deprecated warning.

Comment: The first conversion is already correct. Albeit for matching fixed strings `strstr()` might suffice even.

Comment: Thank you @Ultimater - that did the trick.

Comment: @mario The php manual says (in one of those cute Notes) not to use `strstr()` to check the existence of a substring -- `strpos()` is the "lighter"/ better suited call.

Comment: @mickmackusa It is, performance-wise of course. But `strstr` is usually more legible (without the !== decoration). Still not sure if the manual advise is really newcomer friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means, that the function eregi() is likely to get deleted from the language.

Please use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php).

While you still can use eregi(), at a certain point of time your application might not be able to execute any more.

**That said: Your code posted is far to big to get a detailed answer.**

Comment: It has been deleted as of 7.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I snipped the code. As said in 1st post, I tried preg_match after reading other threads but don't know enough php to fix the rest of the line.